# Fancy Box Position Absolute Top Left

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I was hoping you could all solve a little problem I have had with using the JQuery Fancy Box Plugin.

My issue is I am trying to use absolute position so that something always appears in the top left of the overlay reagardless of the overlays size.

http://www.csr500.co.uk/websites/v9/preview.html

Now what I would like is for the jQ and the FW icons, currently in the bottom left to be positioned in the top left, in a similar fashion to the non overlay mode.

The way that I have done it means that the text in the title tag does not show up on hover, which is what I want however from what I can tell this restricts me only access to the fancybox-title-inside-wrap class rather than the fancy-box-outer class.

Any help in sorting out this issue reaqlly would be very much appreciated.

Thanking you all in adavnce

Cheers

Cameron

Comment: But the overlay is the dark zone of fancybox, and it always take full size of the browser, so you just want the fancybox popup to appear at 0,0 all the time ?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea : why you don't take the icons out of the `title` section and create a new (hidden) `div` with them like

```
<div class="iconsPlaceHolder" style="display: none">
    <div class="overlay-technologies">
        <div class="overlay-technology-1">
            <div class="dev-icon"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay-technology-2">
            <div class="web-icon"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Notice** the new class `iconsPlaceHolder`, but can be anything you want.

Then just append them to your fancybox using the `beforeShow` callback like

```
beforeShow: function () {
    $(".overlay-technologies").clone().appendTo(".fancybox-inner");          
}
```

**Notice** that I am appending the `.overlay-technologies` selector, which is the child of my placeholder (`.iconsPlaceHolder`). Also **notice** that I have to `clone` the selector before `appendTo` because it would be moved from its position in the document's flow and cleared when fancybox closes otherwise.  Of course, it requires the proper style and position.

Check **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vBf8j/)**

Comment: Hello JFK, thank you for getting back to me. What I probably forgot to mention was that I would like different icons to appear in different overlays, not the same one in each overlay. I have updated my code and the link can again be found here http://www.csr500.co.uk/websites/v9/preview.html but I would like different icons and different numbers in each one rather than simply the 'last' icons to appear in all of them, any help in sorting this issue out really would be very much appreciated. Thank you Cameron

Comment: So the left item should have icons 1 (dev) and 2 (web), the middle item should have icons 3 (about) and 4 (contact) and the far right should have icons 5 (html) and 6 (css) rather than all of them having icons 5 and 6.